# Phonegap app not opening camera

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have an app that I hired a company to build using Phonegap. The company is no longer able to support me with launching the app onto iTunes.

I have loaded the app and can compile it in Xcode. However the camera function is not working. I have tested the app before from a file they sent me and the camera function worked.

Is there special settings that you have to set in xcode 4 besides what is typical in order to use the camera?

Answer (score 1):

You may be compiling for a different SDK. Make sure you are using the same one as before.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter about the SDK you are working with.. the whole point of phonegap is to expose the native API's to javascript.  So it's not the SDK, its the javascript.  I am actually working on this now.. I will get back to you with my findings.